# MUI TextField hover, white border

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

So I've spent hours now trying to figure out what you would think should be pretty simple but isn't. I've been through the inspect tool on Chrome and I don't see any style that applies a hover of any kind for the fieldset, which is where I believe it is coming from.
So my problem is as follows... I want a simple outlined input. The border should be black and the focused border should be blue... But whenever I set this, every time I hover over the input I get a white border popping up... Great, you would think just setting on hover border to transparent would be the solution... Kinda, but nope, when you do that and when the input is in the active state, if you hover over the input, the border on the input goes transparent...
Which is not exactly the desired effect...
I want zero hover effect on my input but I can't for the life of me find a solution for this. I looked through the docs, and StackOverflow, and googled countless phrases... I mean, come on how hard does something like this have to be? lol
Can someone please give me an idea on how to make the input border or fieldset border on hover not be a thing?

https://imgur.com/a/OCm1y27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after hours of messing around with this, I finally have figured out a solution to my problem. Turns out the border is actually coming from the notchedOutline. So I set the borderWidth to 0 and the color to transparent and that disables the hover effect from the input. To add a static border to the input you can put a border around the input itself rather than the notched outline. So this ended up being my code that fixed the problem... Man, what a pain.

```
MuiOutlinedInput: {
  styleOverrides: {
   input: {
    padding: "3px 3px 3px 10px",
    border: "1px solid #333333",
},
  notchedOutline: {
  borderWidth: 0,
  borderColor: "transparent",
  },
},
},
```